# How do I send commands to a command line process

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have a Garry's Mod server I want it to autorestart every 12 hours. I can make a script where it executes a command every 12 hours but I dont know how to send the command "quit" to the process "srcds.exe". I saw something like 
`echo quit |srcds.exe`
I tried it but it didnt work. How do I do this using MS-DOS (batch file)?

Comment: There are addons for gmod servers that are better suited for this. Not saying that this is a bad question or that it's a bad way to do it, but the addons are more user-friendly and have more capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the taskkill command:

```
taskkill /f /im srcds.exe
```

And it kill the tasks srcds.exe

Comment: I don't want to just kill the process and lose some data. I want to be able to send commands not kill processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you can edit the program you want to send a command to, you can try inserting this command line into it where you want it to terminate:

```
if exist (directory)\(triggering file).txt del /Q (directory)\(triggering file).txt & quit
```

This will scan for the file that the triggering program will create, delete it, and then quit the program. If the file is not present, the program will ignore the line and move on as if the command line wasn't there.

The triggering program can be run whenever you want to terminate the main program. This program should be:

```
echo.>"(directory)\(triggering file).txt"
exit
```

Above was the simplest way of doing this. If you want to make it more "idiot proofed" you can add as the first line of the main program:

```
echo.>"(directory)\(main run file).txt"
```

This will write a .txt file the same way the triggering program does. This tells the triggering program that the main program is running and it can terminate it. You will also have to change the above IF statement in the main program to read:

```
if exist (directory)\(triggering file).txt del /Q (directory)\(main run file).txt & del /Q (directory)\(triggering file).txt & quit
```

Finally, change the triggering program to read:

```
if not exist (directory)\(main run file).txt quit
echo.>"(directory)\(triggering file).txt"
quit
```

Just some final notes, wherever I have "(directory)" replace it and the ()'s with an otherwise unused, untouched directory. Wherever you see "(triggering file)" replace it and the ()'s with a filename that is common with all other places you see "(triggering file)". Same goes to "(main run file)" but it must have a different name then "(triggering file)".

I know this might be confusing. Don't be afraid to comment and ask quesions. I will be happy to clarify.